# How can I serve static web site from s3 through node expressjs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

currently I use `app.use(express.static('public'))` and my files located in the public folder of my node js express app and its working good.
However, I would like to store those files (index.html, etc) in my s3 bucket (so multiple apps can use this website).
I tried

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('link-to-s3-file/index.html'); 
 });
```

with no success...

Answer (score 15):

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. There's a reasonably recent and well documented middleware module for this on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-proxy)

From the docs:

```
app.get('/media/*', s3Proxy({
  bucket: 'bucket_name',
  prefix: 'optional_s3_path_prefix',
  accessKeyId: 'aws_access_key_id',
  secretAccessKey: 'aws_secret_access_key',
  overrideCacheControl: 'max-age=100000'
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted `/foo` to match a `/foo.html` on a different s3 bucket. I used the following to do so:

```
app.get('/:thePath', function(req, res) {
    var key = "saved/" + req.params.thePath;
    if(key.indexOf(".html") === -1) {
        key = key + ".html";
    }

    s3.getObject({ Bucket: "just-read", Key: key })
   .on('httpHeaders', function (statusCode, headers) {
        res.set('Content-Length', headers['content-length']);
        res.set('Content-Type', "text/html");
        this.response.httpResponse.createUnbufferedStream()
            .pipe(res);
    })
    .send();
});
```