# How can I serve static web site from firebase hosting through node expressjs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-hosting

Re-using question from [How can I serve static web site from s3 through node expressjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40262009/2797942) but used in the context of Firebase.

Currently I use app.use(express.static('public')) and my files located in the public folder of my node js express app and its working good. However, I would like to store those files (index.html, etc) in in our Firebase Hosting (so multiple apps can use this website). I tried

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('*-firebaseapp.com/index.html'); 
 });
```

Are there any specific methods for a static website hosted in Firebase to be rendered to an Express App?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The [`res.sendFile()` method](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) defines its `path` parameter as:

> `path` must be an absolute path to the file.

Your Express function is running in Cloud Functions, which is a serverless container on Google's infrastructure. Firebase Hosting is running in a different infrastructure, with much of the serving happening on edge caches.

The Cloud Functions code doesn't have access to the file system of the hosting infrastructure.

So if you want to serve files from Firebase Hosting, you will have to request them through HTTP(S), similar to what any client will have to do. Alternatively, you can consider deploying the HTML files into your Cloud Functions container, by putting them inside the folder where you have your `index.js`/`index.ts` file too.